# CSS3 transition only scale

Tags: html, css

A simple question.

When I hover the element, element should be scale. Working fine. Problem is I have some background colors also applying. I want to get rid of this background transition.

Following is my code.

```
.scale{
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.scale:hover{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I have changes the transition-property to `width, height, top, right, bottom, left`

My pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yAGBj

Comment: r u looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/s9wuukty/

Comment: Ah, yes @SureshPonnukalai Thanks. Just a simple overwrite. Please post the answer

Comment: fine. answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment above, just add the `background:red` in your `scale:hover` class.

```
.scale:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
background:red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s9wuukty/)

Answer (score 4):

Change your `transition` to only affect the desired CSS properties rather than `all`:

```css
transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
```

[**CodePen demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jlApL).

Comment: Thanks, Its only changing the background color. I need to stop changing the color and do the scale part

Comment: @Mifas it's changing the background colour because you have `.box:hover{ background:blue; }`. The demo I've provided only transitions the `transform`, the `background` is changed instantaneously. This can be confirmed by increasing the transition time like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xsLbo.